# How to get files from IIS Physical Path from my C# ASP.NET Core 8 MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-8.0

I'm not sure if my question is correct but here is my problem:

In my IIS server, my sites `Physical Path` is this: `C:\staging\appsdev`:

[image]

Now, that directory looks like this:

[image]

And this is the IIS directory where my released files are located:

[image]

Now, my sites works fine if I add the `Navbar.json` to the root directory of the site (`C:\Staging\ILS-dev\IMC\`). What I'm trying to do is to move the `Navbar.json` to the `Physical Path` (which already exists), but my code cannot find that directory.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
public class NavigationViewComponent: ViewComponent
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

    public NavigationViewComponent(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        string contentRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
        var navbarJsonFiles = FindNavbarJson(contentRootPath);

        var jsonRawData = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(navbarJsonFiles);
        List<MenuItem> menuItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MenuItem>>(jsonRawData)!;
        return View("_ILIMSNavigation", menuItems);
    }

    public string FindNavbarJson(string rootPath)
    {
        var navbarJsonFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootPath, "Navbar.json", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (var navbarJsonFile in navbarJsonFiles)
        {
            return navbarJsonFile;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The code above only works if there is a `Navbar.json` present in the sites folder `(C:\Staging\ILS-dev\IMC\)`. But I want to centralize the `Navbar.json` and should be located in the sites `Physical Path` `(C:\Staging\appsdev\)`.

Comment: I don't quite follow. `C:\Staging\appsdev\` is the physical path of the website and are you able to see the website at all when you are pointing to this path? `C:\Staging\ILS-dev\IMC\` is the path on `IIS` on your local machine?

Comment: @RahulSharma IIS is installed in a physical windows server. we connect to that server and deploy the released version of asp mvc there. Not really sure but that is how the files are being structured. We have around 15 projects in one solution and IMC is one of the 15 projects.

Comment: You application host at the `C:\Staging\ILS-dev\IMC\` , but now you want to make this application's aoosetting.json file into the `C:\Staging\appsdev\`. Am I understand right?

Comment: there is a file called Navbar.json in the `C:\Staging\appsdev` which is needed by the application that is hosted in `C:\Staging\ILS-dev\IMC`

Comment: OK, why you don't directly using the file reader with the static pathC:\Staging\appsdev to read it?

Comment: @BrandoZhang I can't do that, we have multiple environments, dev, test, uat and prod and this is the easiest way (at least for now).

Comment: But for now its impossible to use the `_webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath` to get the folder which is not current application's root folder. How about read it from the environment variable? Put the different path for the different environment variable ?